# Eclipse editor shows some different characters as background pattern. How to disable?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

Eclipse editor shows some weird characters as background pattern. Finding it uneasy to edit code. Please suggest a way to disable it. Thanks for the help.

[image: Eclipse editor - pattern images as background]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have Eclipse set to show tabs. Under Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors. There should be an option for 'Show whitespace characters'

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can **ON - OFF** from eclipse toolbar
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Under `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors`. There's a checkbox called "Show whitespace characters". Uncheck that option. Right now it's showing you tabs with that symbol.